# Turtlebot dying when launching kinect

Tags: kinect, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Everytime I try to launch the kinect it gets stuck after setting the depth frame id and then the power system dies shortly after.

turtlebot@turtlebot:~$ roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch
... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/e892ee8a-a055-11e1-97ca-9cb70d1ffd03/roslaunch-turtlebot-17123.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://10.5.6.187:49248/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /kinect_laser/max_height
- /openni_camera/depth_rgb_rotation
- /rosdistro
- /openni_camera/image_mode
- /openni_camera/image_time_offset
- /openni_camera/projector_depth_baseline
- /kinect_laser_narrow/output_frame_id
- /openni_camera/depth_mode
- /kinect_laser_narrow/max_height
- /openni_camera/depth_frame_id
- /openni_camera/depth_time_offset
- /kinect_laser/output_frame_id
- /rosversion
- /openni_camera/depth_registration
- /openni_camera/debayering
- /openni_camera/depth_rgb_translation
- /kinect_laser/min_height
- /pointcloud_throttle/max_rate
- /openni_camera/shift_offset
- /kinect_laser_narrow/min_height
- /openni_camera/rgb_frame_id

NODES
/
kinect_breaker_enabler (turtlebot_node/kinect_breaker_enabler.py)
openni_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
openni_camera (nodelet/nodelet)
pointcloud_throttle (nodelet/nodelet)
kinect_laser (nodelet/nodelet)
kinect_laser_narrow (nodelet/nodelet)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.5.6.187:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[kinect_breaker_enabler-1]: started with pid [17144]
process[openni_manager-2]: started with pid [17145]
process[openni_camera-3]: started with pid [17146]
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [17147]
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [17150]
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [17159]
[kinect_breaker_enabler-1] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/e892ee8a-a055-11e1-97ca-9cb70d1ffd03/kinect_breaker_enabler-1*.log
[ INFO] [1337282893.695750053]: [/openni_camera] Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1337282893.696185440]: [/openni_camera] 1. device on bus 001:12 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'B00362724570104B'
[ WARN] [1337282893.699195269]: [/openni_camera] device_id is not set! Using first device.
[ INFO] [1337282893.798186534]: [/openni_camera] Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:12 with serial number 'B00362724570104B'
[ INFO] [1337282893.860259880]: rgb_frame_id = 'camera_rgb_optical_frame'
[ INFO] [1337282893.869042233]: depth_frame_id = 'camera_depth_optical_frame'

--GETS STUCK HERE and then the power system goes down (Green led on iCreate cable goes out)--

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34239/turtlebot-dying-when-launching-kinect/) by [TaylorC](https://answers.ros.org/users/2399/taylorc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2012-05-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well the stuck issue was simply me not realizing that the program was just running. The power down issue is that I swapped to a new laptop_battery.py and it seems to not show the correct charge for the iCreate battery now. Will have to just keep tabs on charging it until I have time to look into it.

---

Originally posted by [TaylorC](https://answers.ros.org/users/2399/taylorc/) with karma: 148 on 2012-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1